# tableview data title missing in two cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

i am upgraded the code then the below code title has 22 objects,in 16 object empty and the like another object is nil.why it happen and i write code like elementame is eqale to item like then it works exactly.but when pass the data from one view controller to another it has issue.
    please give solution and in they send the links of each item then the write code for images and discription by using model.

so please help me.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cinejosh.com/rss-feed/4/telugu.html"];
  NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];

 NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

if(urlConnection){
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"the connection failed");
   }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    [self.responseData setLength:0];       
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    self.cnnParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:self.responseData];
    self.cnnParser.delegate = self;
    [self.cnnParser parse];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.homeActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [self.activityView setHidden:YES];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertView.delegate = self;
    [alertView show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    titlesTag = NO;
    datesTag = NO;
    descriptionsTag = NO;
    linksTag = NO;
    itemsTag = NO;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        itemsTag = YES;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
       titlesTag = YES;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"])
    {
        linksTag = YES;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
       descriptionsTag = YES;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
    {
        datesTag = YES;
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

{

    if(titlesTag == YES && itemsTag == YES)
    {

        [titlesArray addObject:string];
        NSLog(@"title %lu",[titlesArray count]);
    }
    else if(linksTag == YES && itemsTag == YES)
    {
        [self.linksArray addObject:string];
    }
    else if(descriptionsTag == YES && itemsTag == YES)
    {
        [self.descriptionsArray addObject:string];
    }
    else if(datesTag == YES && itemsTag == YES)
    {

        [self.datesArray addObject:string];
           NSLog(@"date %lu",(unsigned long)[datesArray count]);
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        titlesTag = NO;
       //  itemsTag = NO;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"])
    {
        linksTag = NO;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
        descriptionsTag = NO;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
    {
        datesTag = NO;
      //  itemsTag = NO;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqual:@"item"])
    {
        itemsTag=NO;
    }

}
```